# Interpolation polynomial Challenge

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, contest-math, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation

suppose $p(x)=x^k-x^t,   k \neq t $ (k,t is a positive integer). function q(x) be a Interpolation polynomial from degree lower or equal n, to data $i=1,...,n+1, (x_i ,p(x_i))$. if ----------- then $p(x)=q(x)$.

my professor wrote a solution for  ----------- as:

$n \leq max(k,t)$

why this is true?

i think $n \geq max(k,t)$ is True.

any hint or idea?

Comment: The highest degree polynomial interpolated from $n$ points is $n-1$. A ${\rm max}(k,t)$ degree poly needs at least ${\rm max}(k,t)+1$ points to be fully described.

Comment: Dear @ja72. you means my professor rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll prove you right using the [Lagrange Interpolation error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Interpolation_error):

> Let $q$ be the interpolation polynomial to a function $p$ with data points $(x_i, p(x_i))_{i=0}^{n}$. If $p$ is $n+1$ times differentiable then:
>
> $$ p(x) - q(x) = \frac{p^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} \prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-x_i)$$

Let $p(x) := x^k - x^t$. Then for $n \geq \max (k,t)$ we find that

$$ p^{(n+1)}(x) = 0$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Using the Lagrange error we get:

\begin{align*} p(x) - q(x) &= \frac{p^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} \prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-x_i)\\
&= 0 \\
&\Rightarrow p(x) = q(x)
 \end{align*}

Your professor confused $\leq$ with $\geq$.

Answer (score 0):

The professor is correct. With $n+1$ points the highest degree polynomial defined is $n$ and the degree of $p(x)$ is ${\rm max}(k,t)$. So for $p(x)=q(x)$ the order of $q(x)$ must be equal or less than the order of $p(x)$, or

$$ n \le {\rm max}(k,t)$$

Comment: would you please add a proof?

Comment: Nope. You asked for a hint or idea and this is what you get. You will have to devise a proof on your own.

Comment: it's no acceptable. so maybe you wrong.

Comment: I can live with that.

Comment: i not accept it. because i'm not sure. thanks anyway. waiting for others.

Comment: Say $p(x)=x^2-x^3$. You can match this with a degree-1 polynomial?